# C++ Debug assertion failed, using Windows.h mutex

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, assertion

I have a problem caused by this code:

```
char KernelFS::mount(Partition* part) {
WaitForSingleObject(mutexFS,INFINITE);
int pos;
for(pos=0; pos<26; pos++)
    if(mountedPartitions[pos] == 0)
        break;

if(pos < 26) {

    mountedPartitions[pos] = part;
    bitVectors[pos] = new BitVector(part);
    fileEvidention[pos] = new ListHandler();

    openedFiles[pos] = 0;
    forbidOpening[pos] = false;

    ReleaseMutex(mutexFS);
    return intToChar(pos);
}
else {
    ReleaseMutex(mutexFS);
    return '0';
}
```

}

and

char KernelFS::format(char part){

```
WaitForSingleObject(mutexFS,INFINITE);
forbidOpening[charToInt(part)] = true;
ReleaseMutex(mutexFS);

while(openedFiles[charToInt(part)]>0)
    WaitForSingleObject(unmountSem,INFINITE);


WaitForSingleObject(mutexFS,INFINITE);
//  write fresh bit vector to cluster 0 of partition
bitVectors[charToInt(part)]->formatBitVector();
openedFiles[charToInt(part)] = 0;
forbidOpening[charToInt(part)] = false;
delete fileEvidention;    //!!***!!
fileEvidention[charToInt(part)] = new ListHandler();

// some other stuff, irrelevant

ReleaseMutex(mutexFS);
return 1;
```

}

There are 3 thread executing, 1 is blocked and two are running through this code; 
they first call mount, then format (each has its own argument Partition object, p1 and p2).
The first time mount is called, it always goes through - then there is an assertion failure at random during one of the next calls of mount/format by any of the two running threads.

Usually, it fails during thread 1 - it calls mount(..) completes it, then calls format(...) and fails around:
delete fileEvidention[charToInt(pos)];
(in debug mode, when I reach this instruction, even if I try to go into with F11, there is an assertion failure)

In case it matters... this is the initialization:

```
char KernelFS::firstLetter = 'A';                   //  'A' = 65
Partition* KernelFS::mountedPartitions[26] = {0};   //  init. no partitions are mounted
BitVector* KernelFS::bitVectors[26] = {0};          //  init. no partitions are mounted
bool KernelFS::forbidOpening[26] = {false};
long KernelFS::openedFiles[26] = {0};
ListHandler* KernelFS::fileEvidention[26] = {0};

HANDLE KernelFS::mutexFS = CreateMutex(0,0,0);
HANDLE KernelFS::unmountSem = CreateSemaphore(0,0,INFINITE,0);
```

I have never had this error before, I have no idea how to debug this nor what could cause it. 
Thanks for the help, in advance.

EDIT:
when i remove the marked line of code (and ignore the memory leak) there is no assertion failure. What is this witchcraft ?

! :)

Comment: which line causes the assert? What is the message of assert?

Comment: the assertion is caused at the line that has the comment after it
delete fileEvidention[...]; 
in format(...)

the assertion msg is:

Debug assertion failed!

path..
line 52..

Expression: _BLOCK_TYPE_IS_VALID(pHead->nBlockUse)

Answer (score 0):

Solved. should be
delete fileEvidention[charToInt(part)];
......